# cv2.error when training image (Overload Resolution Failed)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm learning opencv via the following link [link](https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/OpenCV-Python-Series) [link2](https://youtu.be/PmZ29Vta7Vc). And I got error related to image training process for face recognition. Please correct me or help with the problem I'm having. thank you

**System Information :**

- OpenCV 4.5.2.52
- Python 3.9.5

**Detailed Description**

I need to train an images by using the code below and the results was :

```
- OpenCV/faces-train.py", line 50, in <module>
    recognizer.train(x_train, np.array(y_labels))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'train'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'
```

**Code**

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import pickle

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
image_dir = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "images")

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

current_id = 0
label_ids = {}
y_labels = []
x_train = []

for root, dirs, files, in os.walk(image_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith("png") or file.endswith("jpg") or file.endswith("jpeg") :
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            label = os.path.basename(root).replace(" ", "-").lower()
            # print(label, path)
            if not label in label_ids:
                label_ids[label] = current_id
                current_id += 1
                
            id_ = label_ids[label]
            # print(label_ids)
            
            y_labels.append(label)
            x_train.append(path)
            pil_image = Image.open(path).convert("L")
            image_array = np.array(pil_image, "uint8")
            # print(image_array)
            
            faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image_array, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)
            
            for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
                roi = image_array[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                x_train.append(roi)
                y_labels.append(id_)
                
# print(y_labels)
# print(x_train)

with open("labels.pickle", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(label_ids, f)
    
recognizer.train(x_train, np.array(y_labels))
recognizer.save("trainner.yml")
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the following lines:

- y_labels.append(label)
- x_train.append(path)

you don't really need to append the labels or the paths since you are basically training the face recognizer to recognise/categorise faces. Likewise, you wouldnt need the path to your images as it is also not necessary. Guessing this is what caused the error!

Do let me know if the fix works! Cheers :)